# [giraffe][rickshaw] How to dynamically scaly Y axis on positive and negative sides

Tags: rickshaw, giraffe.js

I am using Giraffe (https://github.com/kenhub/giraffe) to draw some graphs based on some graphite metrics.

The values for one of the graphs can go positive as well as negative. I do not want to set explicit scale for the graph using "min" and "max". Is there a way that the graph can dynamically scale and display the negative values as well?

Currently, the graph scales dynamically on the positive y axis but the values on negative y axis are not displayed.

Thanks!

Comment: Coudn't post as an answer - but this was resolved using the details here: https://github.com/kenhub/giraffe/issues/49

"min": "auto" as a workaround until the fix makes it to giraffe codebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the creator of [Giraffe](http://giraffe.kenhub.com/).

The [issue](https://github.com/kenhub/giraffe/issues/49) was resolved in the latest version. Thanks for reporting it.

Older versions can set `min: 'auto'` in the `dashboards.js` file.